# UIScrollView Performance Tips?

Tags: ios, performance, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView that is animating a lot of UIViews (probably too many).  Also, these UIViews represent "pages", and sometimes multiple pages are stacked on top of each other, resulting in a "pile" of pages (setup by adding subviews to a given view).

I know that scrolling an excessive number of UIViews can have poor performance, but I was wondering if anybody had some general tips for me to improve performance?

For now, doing drawing manually in drawRect is not something I would like to consider because it would mess up various "page pile" animations.  I will keep it in mind for a last resort, but I'd definitely like to avoid it if possible.

Update:
The cause of the performance hit has been determined and is two fold: I'm using antialiasing and shadows on all my UIViews.  When I toggle them both off, the performance issues are resolved!  However, I obviously don't want to just toggle them off :)

I'm creating my shadows like so:

```
self.imageView.layer.opaque = YES;
        self.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
        self.imageView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-4, 0);
        self.imageView.layer.shadowRadius = 2.5;
        self.imageView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.15;
        self.imageView.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(
                                                                                      self.bounds.origin.x,
                                                                                      self.bounds.origin.y,
                                                                                      self.bounds.size.width + 8,
                                                                                      self.bounds.size.height + 2)].CGPath;
```

Any tips to improve the performance?

As far as antialiasing, it is almost a necessity.  The problem is that those "offset pages" are slightly rotated AND my pages have a 1 pixel border.  Slightly rotated with a 1 pixel border without antialiasing looks awful.  I am simply enabling antialiasing in the .plist by setting "Renders with Edge Antialiasing" to YES.

Any suggestions on how to improve my shadow/antialiasing performance would be appreciated.

Comment: One tip is to use CATiledLayer if you can.  This will speed up rendering by breaking it into chunks that can be processed by multiple cores.

Comment: Instead of a scrollview, have you considered showing each page in a separate view that you can wade thru, maybe with a neat animation?

Comment: Funny you mention that, that actually already exists! To elaborate... The UIScrollView I'm talking about shows multiple documents, each with potentially multiple pages.  The "stacked pages" effect is achieved by adding additional UIViews and offsetting them (a maximum of 4 offset pages is shown so as to limit extra UIViews), but this is creating an overabundance of UIViews, slowing scroll performance (I think).  If you tap a document, there is a fancy animation and you go to that separate view that you are mentioning where you can mess with the pages :) (I think that's what you meant anyway)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How many UIViews are "a lot"? And what kind of views are we talking about?
100 UIViews usually aren't a problem, if they don't require complex drawing.
However, 10 `UIWebView` instances rendering PDFs are a different story...

Make sure your views are only laid out and drawn if necessary (= only if they're actually visible). You can check this by creating breakpoints in the view's `layoutSubviews`, for example.

Also, use opaque `UIView` elements whenever possible. This makes drawing more efficient, as views below opaque elements don't have to be drawn.

If you happen to have custom `CALayer` instances (e.g. `CAShapeLayer` with shadows etc.) that require a lot of processing but rarely change, you might want to consider enable rasterization on those: `yourLayer.shouldRasterize = YES;`
This accelerates drawing by caching the rendered composite image.

Comment: Okay, I did some more investigating and I've narrowed down the problem.  Will update main question.  But you helped me realize I'm really not showing THAT many UIViews, so the performance issue must (and is) related to another issue: antialiasing and shadows.

Comment: And to answer your question, probably around 45-60 views total (15-20 of which have shadows)

Comment: @MikeS: You've already done the most important thing to improve performance: Setting a `shadowPath`. Did you try enabling rasterization on the layer with the shadow?

Comment: Oddly enough, enabling rasterization hurts performance quite a bit as oppose to helping it.  Yeah, I learned the hard way that creating shadows without a `shadowPath` usually results in poor performance.

Comment: @MikeS: Rasterization only improves performance if the view doesn't have to be drawn very often. I suppose the overlapping layers result in a lot of drawing. On my iPhone 4S, a small demo project with 12 `UIImageViews` with large shadows scrolls very nicely, so I suppose there's something different about your views - or the ones below them.

Comment: I only had about 15 labels but all of them with shadows and the scrolling was very poor on slower devices. Your idea of rasterizing worked for me: yourLayer.shouldRasterize = YES; Many thanks!